# Sorting Nulls and Empty Strings at Last in Sequelize Order By

Tags: postgresql, null, sequelize.js, sql-order-by

I want to sort Nulls and Empty stings at the last in sequelize order by.

Here is the query I am able to run:

```
data = await Provider.findAll({
            where: {
              search
            },
            order: [
              ['lastName', 'ASC NULLS LAST']
            ]
          });
```

Postgress by default sort the Null values at last, but for empty string it doesn't take it as NULL rather it takes it as a string of length 0.
I want to sort the values with empty string at last, whether the empty string is at the first or at the last name it should be sorted at the end of list, giving preference to the names having both names.
I am using postgress with sequelize.

Update:
Following is the result I'm getting:

| lastName | firstName |
| --- | --- |
| l_name1 | f_name1 |
| l_name2 | empty_str |
| l_name3 | f_name3 |
| l_name4 | f_name4 |
| l_name5 | f_name5 |

Following is the expected result:

| lastName | firstName |
| --- | --- |
| l_name1 | f_name1 |
| l_name3 | f_name3 |
| l_name4 | f_name4 |
| l_name5 | f_name5 |
| l_name2 | empty_str |

For lastName is empty but firstName is not empty (expected result):

| lastName | firstName |
| --- | --- |
| l_name1 | f_name1 |
| l_name4 | f_name4 |
| l_name5 | f_name5 |
| l_name2 | empty_str |
| empty_str | f_name3 |

Answer (score 0):

you can put multiple conditions in order by like this

```
order: [
    ['lastName', 'ASC NULLS LAST'],
    [sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN lastName = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'), 'DESC']
],
```

Let me know if this works or not

Comment: Not working for me, but the NULLIIF is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option.

If you want to order null OR empty string at last without ordering null or empty string before another, you can use `NULLIF`.

```
order: [
    [sequelize.fn('NULLIF', sequelize.col('lastName'), ''), 'NULLS LAST']
]
```

**Update**

Add firstName ordering.

```
order: [
    [sequelize.fn('NULLIF', sequelize.col('lastName'), ''), 'NULLS LAST'],
    [sequelize.fn('NULLIF', sequelize.col('firstName'), ''), 'NULLS LAST']
]
```

This will result in the order like this.

| lastName | firstName |
| --- | --- |
| Smith | Alice |
| Smith | Bob |
| Smith | null |
| Smith |  |
| null | Alice |
|  | Alice |
| null | null |

**Update2**

Order in the following criterion.

- Both lastName & firstName are not null and not empty
- Either lastName or firstName is not null or not empty
- Both lastName & firstName are null or empty

```js
order: [
    [sequelize.literal(`
         CASE 
             WHEN NULLIF("lastName", '') IS NULL AND NULLIF("firstName", '') IS NULL THEN 2
             WHEN NULLIF("lastName", '') IS NULL OR NULLIF("firstName", '') IS NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
         END
    `)]
]
```

Comment: It works, thanks for the answer, is it a way to also apply it to 'first_name' as well?
Meaning adding an AND condition, checking if there's empty string in both first or last name.

Comment: Cool, just to be clear, could you add some examples(both non null, lastname null, firstname null, both null) to show how it should be ordered? and add a note if a certain order doesn't matter(ex: firstname null and lastname null can be in either order)?

Comment: Basically I want to put Null or Empty String values at the end of list whether there's a Null or empty string in the 'last' or 'first' name.
Following are the 4 cases:
1-Both Not Null: The list should be ordered alphabetically by last name.
2-Both Null: the list should be order alphabetically by last name but the empty string should be at the end of list.
3-Last name null:  same as 2.
4-First name Null: the list should be order alphabetically by last name but the empty string in first name should be at the end of list. Even if there's value in last name.
The Nullif covers first 3 cases.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check if the ordering looks like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately the 'first' name case is not giving the required result. When the first name is empty the order is according to last name. The other 3 cases work fine. I was thinking like if there's an AND condition we can make i.e., NULLIF(last_name, '') AND NULLIF(first_name, ''). That would probably get it solved.

Comment: Could you update your question to describe how the  firstName should be ordered?  You can use my example table. from the text, I am not quite getting what order you like

Comment: I have updated the question, the order of firstName doesn't matter, if it is empty or Null it should be at the end of list, giving preference to the first and last names having non-empty values. But the list should be sorted according to the lastName. I hope it explains my question, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What about when the lastName is empty but firstName is not empty?  where does this record should go?

Comment: I have updated the question again. If lastName is empty but firstName is not empty then it should also be at end of list, can be either above or below the 'firstName' empty string. The result that you provided in your updated answer is what I expect, but the sequelize order by query for firstName is not working for me. The lastName NULLIF check is covering the bothNotEmpty, bothEmpty and lastNameEmpty cases.

Comment: Updated.  Please check and see if it matches with your expectation.

Comment: It works but the sorting is gone, how to add the sorting functionality for lastNmae?

Comment: Update: I was able to get the required result. I have posted the solution I came up with as an answer. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the required result for my problem with the help of Emma's answer.
Basically I wanted the sorting to be done on ‘last name’ basis and the people with missing ‘last_name’ or 'first_name' to be shown at the end of search list giving preference to people having both first and last names.

I was able to get the required result by adding Case statement in literal. For those not having knowledge of 'sequelize.literal', it is used to write raw SQL queries while using sequelize.

What the 'sequelize.literal' does it that it checks if either of the first or last name is equal to empty string, then it makes that row as NULL. Then the sorting is done on 'last_name' putting all the Null values at the last of list.

```
data = await Provider.findAll({
            where: {
              search
            },
            order: [
              [sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN last_name = '' OR first_name = '' THEN NULL ELSE 0 END`), 'ASC'],
              ['lastName', 'ASC NULLS LAST']
            ],
          });
```